# How to fix the internationalization error on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, internationalization, android-manifest

I'm doing the internationalization of the app.

I am getting the following error message:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] Unknown failure (Failure) Error while Installing APK
```

Exception on console:

```
01-17 22:47:48.079 1792-1948/? W/PackageManager: Failed parse during installPackageLI
                                             android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: /data/app/vmdl1927641617.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #53): <provider> does not include authorities attribute
                                                 at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApk(PackageParser.java:902)
                                                 at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseClusterPackage(PackageParser.java:800)
                                                 at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:764)
                                                 at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:12646)
                                                 at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap26(PackageManagerService.java)
                                                 at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$9.run(PackageManagerService.java:10581)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                 at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Directory structure:

[image]

[image]

What could be the mistake?

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

I'm trying to internationalize an App from an Android course into the Portuguese language.

This is the Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- This permission is necessary in order for Sunshine to perform network access. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Permissions required by the sync adapter -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ForecastTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:authorities="@string/content_authority"
        android:name=".data.WeatherProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true" />

    <!-- SyncAdapter's dummy authentication service -->
    <service android:name=".sync.SunshineAuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>

    <!-- The SyncAdapter service -->
    <service
        android:name=".sync.SunshineSyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
</application>
```

This is the build file:
[image]

I deleted the strings.xml file the following excerpt from the code.

```
<string name="sync_account_type">sunshine.example.com</string>
<string name="content_authority">com.example.android.sunshine.app</string>
```

It works.

Comment: What makes you think this is an internationalization problem? The error message does not seem to indicate that. The pt string file is red. Have you tried to delete it? It works after that? Have you looked at line 35? (as the message in the stack is "... at Binary XML file line #53")

Comment: @Miltex: Be sure that you have your package name in small letters. It would cause this kind of problem. If possible, please paste your manifest file and build.gradle file.

Comment: @MihaiNita When I include the strings.xml file the error occurs.

Comment: When I delete the values-pt directory it works.